# change the column name while selecting from dyanamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Hi I have attendence query which will generate the attendence report with using PIVOT function

Here's the procedure :

```
declare  @in_date DATETIME       

/*Select all the stagign entries related to promotion id and investment type id */    
  /* also only those staging daat related interface status tracking*/

  -- Getting all distinct dates into a temporary table #Dates
    SELECT a.date as full_date_of_attendence INTO #Dates
    FROM dbo.getFullmonth(@in_date) a
    ORDER BY a.date



    -- The number of days will be dynamic. So building
    -- a comma seperated value string from the dates in #Dates
    SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, full_date_of_attendence, 106)
                                    + ']','[' + CONVERT(varchar, full_date_of_attendence, 106) + ']')
    FROM    #Dates
    ORDER BY full_date_of_attendence


    --select @cols

    ---- Building the query with dynamic dates

SET @qry =
    'SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT admission_id, attendence_status , date_of_attendence
    FROM dbo.tblattendence)emp
    PIVOT (MAX(attendence_status) FOR date_of_attendence IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat'    



    -- Executing the query
    EXEC(@qry)

    -- Dropping temporary tables
    DROP TABLE #Dates
```

here is the output of the above query::

```
admission_id    01 May 2013 02 May 2013 03 May 2013
2                NULL               1               0
3                NULL               1               1
4                NULL               0               0
5                NULL               0               1
```

Here I want to change the names of the columns as `01,02,03......`
and I want the values 1 as 'P' and 0 as 'A'

can anyone would help me to achieve this ??

Comment: use Select admission_id as AdmsnId FROM dbo.tblattendence

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes to your code.  If you want a list of the days (1, 2, 3, etc), then you can use the [DAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) function.

Typically when I get a list of columns dynamically, my preference is using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`, I would alter that code to the following:

```
select @colsPiv = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(day(full_date_of_attendence) as varchar(2))) 
                from #Dates
                GROUP BY full_date_of_attendence
                ORDER BY full_date_of_attendence
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Then if you want to replace the `0` with an `A` and a `1` with a `P`, you will want to create a query to get a list of columns to replace the values:

```
select @colsSel = STUFF((SELECT ', case when ' + QUOTENAME(cast(day(full_date_of_attendence) as varchar(2)))+'= 1 then ''P'' else ''A'' end as '+QUOTENAME(cast(day(full_date_of_attendence) as varchar(2)))
                      from #Dates
                      GROUP BY full_date_of_attendence
                      ORDER BY full_date_of_attendence
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')
```

Basically, this is creating a select list similar to this:

```
select case when [1] = 1 then 'P' else 'A' end as [1], ...
```

Then your final query will be:

```
SET @qry =
'SELECT admission_id, '+@colsSel +' 
 FROM
 (
    SELECT admission_id, 
      attendence_status , 
      day(date_of_attendence) date_of_attendence
    FROM dbo.tblattendence
 )emp
 PIVOT 
 (
    MAX(attendence_status) 
    FOR date_of_attendence IN (' + @colsPiv + ')
 ) AS stat'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bce5/6)

Answer (score 0):

Let's change just the two things you wanted to, i.e.

1. `CONVERT(CHAR(2), full_date_of_attendence, 106)` -- use CHAR(2) instead of varchar
2. `CASE attendence_status when 1 then 'P' else 'A' END` in the SELECT...

The code with minimal changes. Hope this helps you see how you can make similar changes in future to other code.

```
declare @in_date DATETIME

/*Select all the stagign entries related to promotion id and investment type id */    
/* also only those staging daat related interface status tracking*/

-- Getting all distinct dates into a temporary table #Dates
SELECT a.date as full_date_of_attendence INTO #Dates
FROM dbo.getFullmonth(@in_date) a
ORDER BY a.date



-- The number of days will be dynamic. So building
-- a comma seperated value string from the dates in #Dates
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') + [' +
        CONVERT(CHAR(2), full_date_of_attendence, 106) + ']'
FROM    #Dates
ORDER BY full_date_of_attendence


--select @cols

---- Building the query with dynamic dates

SET @qry =
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT admission_id, CASE attendence_status when 1 then 'P' else 'A' END, date_of_attendence
FROM dbo.tblattendence)emp
PIVOT (MAX(attendence_status) FOR date_of_attendence IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat'    



-- Executing the query
EXEC(@qry)

-- Dropping temporary tables
DROP TABLE #Dates
```